# How can I verify a job submitted to z/OS using FTP has completed?

Tags: unix, ftp, mainframe

Is there a way to be notified or query when the job has completed if a job submitted to z/OS using FTP from a distributed platform ?

I am using [JESINTERFACELEVEL=2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.4.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r4.halz001/ftpserverjesinterfacelevel.htm)

This is the FTP code used and there are further steps in the shell script that depend on the file created from this job.

```
ftp -Av << END2 >> ${LOGFILE}
     $FTP_HOST
     quote site filetype=jes
     put $jclout
    END2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the FTP DIR Command:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.halu001/dispstatusdirlevel2.htm